# Okhttp3, Hostname cannot be verified in case SSL certificate is issued for IP address

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, retrofit2, android-networking, okhttp

Following exception happens when **OkHttp** tries to connect to a server using IP address:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname 195.168.2.68 not verified:
       certificate: sha256/rxO7r+KJOj2iTLR+MPWF7rNV45BYYQKvhlsb4K6yHXE=
       DN: CN=test sandbox,OU=it,O=abc,L=newyork,ST=western,C=us
       subjectAltNames: []
```

A server has a self-signed SSL Certificate which was generated for server's IP address.

**Base Url is :** *https://195.168.2.68:8092/Mobile/*

Whats going wrong here?

Comment: what's the common name of your certificate?

Comment: I tried with various Values for CN , I used ip also. now cn values is 'test'.

Answer (score 0):

> Hostname 195.168.2.68 not verified

and

> I tried with various Values for CN , I used ip also. now cn values is 'test'.

Since `195.168.2.68` does not match `test` it all works as expected as CommonName is what is mainly being used for matching, so you need either properly issued certificate or you may i.e. delegate `test` domain to point to `195.168.2.68` and use `test` instead of IP to make it match CN. But I'd fix the certificate in first place.